# How do you make a cake with soft fillings baked inside?

Tags: baking, cake

I've seen cakes baked with soft fillings inside like a cream cheese of chocolate buttercream type filling that were obviously baked in there, rather than baking and filling when cold. What are the general techniques for doing this, and do they work with all kinds of fillings?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the cakes you've seen like this? There may be many different methods so it may be very difficult to answer this question completely.

Comment: I've seen filled cupcakes (cut a cone out, then fill) -- typically cakes are torted and fillings spread between the layers.  I've also seen cake pans that end up forming an area that can be filled, such as [Wilton's 'Tasty-Fill'](http://www.wilton.com/heart-tasty-fill-pan/2105-157.html) line.

Comment: Also [Molten Lava Cakes](http://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1014719-molten-chocolate-cake)

Comment: I think some folks are worried this was going to requires a book worth of cake-making advice to answer, so I tried to edit a bit to ask for the general techniques, and then once you see what the options are, you can ask a follow-up question about one of them if you want more detail!

Comment: Why do you believe the fillings were "obviously baked in there, rather than baking and filling when cold"? A buttercream, for example, simply cannot be baked - you'll end up with melted sweetened fat, not buttercream. On the other hand, you can do a *lot* of things with the suitable application of a piping bag. So, Occam's Razor and all that, if I meet a cupcake with a buttercream filling, I conclude that the buttercream was added after baking, rather than positing a strange buttercream-like substance that doesn't melt.

Comment: @Marti that doesn't mean it's not possible... many cakes (particularly bundt cakes) have fillings that are baked inside - Tunnel of Fudge, for example.

Comment: The answer is the easiest one: get a cupcake corer. A quick search on that term on Amazon should lead you right to it. I have two, and they make a complicated taste incredibly simple.

Comment: I think Marti and Catija are both right there: the OP might well have seen cakes that were (skillfully) filled afterwards and would benefit from asking about filling without messing things up, but it's also interesting to ask about what you can actually bake inside of a cake.

Comment: I've seen muffins with like a cream cheese inside or banana bread with cream cheese inside which look like they've been baked with cake mixture and then topped with cream cheese and then topped cake mixture. Wondering what else you can use instead of cream cheese and bake in?

Answer (score 4):

I have a few recipes that are made like that, and the general technique is:

1) Fill the cake tin with half of the batter you would use for a cake;
2) Spoon or pipe the required quantity of filling;
3) Fill the tin with the rest of the batter;
4) PROFIT!

It doesn't work with all fillings, considering that you need to have a filling that is heat resistant (buttercream is a no-no) and that doesn't expand when heated (nothing too airy).

The recipes I have call for brigadeiro (which is a kind of chocolate fudge made with condensed milk, powdered cocoa and butter, previously cooked), dulce de leche, fruit jam and one of them uses a mix of cream cheese, sugar and Bailey's, and all of them work very well.